# Issue with add_rewrite_rule($regex, $redirect, $after);

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I've been through all the relevant posts on this same topic as well as trying ideas from other parts of the internet and I'm still stumped.  This is the first time I've not been able to get something to work in wp.

Yes I click save changes on the admin permalink page after modifying the add_rewrite_rule.

I had an idea of how to tackle a problem and it involved doing rewrites.  So I thought I'd do a quick test of the add_rewrite_rule and just throw it in functions.php.

So I added:

```
function stoneblue_AMP_redir(){

    $regex = 'amp/RID/([0-9]+)/?'; 
    $redirect = 'angel-page/?RID=$1'; 
    $after = 'top';

    add_rewrite_rule($regex, $redirect, $after);

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules( );

}
add_action('init', 'stoneblue_AMP_redir');
```

This gives a .htaccess of:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^amp/RID/([0-9]+)/? /angel-page/?RID=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I end up at the 404.php page:

```
404.php
array(1) {
  ["RID"]=>
  string(8) "707808909"
}
```

Sometimes when I finally breakdown and ask a question I get ideas and am able to solve it, so far nada... ... ...

I've walked away from it, come back still nothing.

Redirects to index.php do work:

```
   $regex = '^bananas$'; 
   $redirect = 'index.php?p=174'; 
   $after = 'top';
   add_rewrite_rule($regex, $redirect, $after);
```

so requesting sub.domain.top/bananas is good no problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't actually explained clearly what you are trying to do, but I gather that you need to redirect from a URL with a folder to a page with a QS parameter instead, and you are getting a 404 error? I'm also confused by your inclusion of htaccess - WP and `add_rewrite_rules` don't actually update htaccess. WP keeps its rewrite rules in the database, so you could use a plugin such as [Rewrite Rules Inspector](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) to check your rule has been written to the db and it is correct.

Comment: It does update the .htaccess file. It added: RewriteRule ^amp/RID/([0-9]+)/? /angel-page/?RID=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: The default behaviour of WP is to add rules to the database and not htaccess, so maybe there is a clash between this rule and the ones in the database? Also, your rule uses `top` which forces it to run before anything else (I presume this is why its not in the db as is standard), so maybe it is being run too early or WP is not able to handle the rewritten URL? Have you checked the WP rules using the Inspector to see? Also what URL is triggering the 404 - is it the original one or the new one? If its the new one, is it correct? Without seeing your actual set up its impossible for us to know.

Comment: It's my understanding that all index.php redirects are handled by WordPress but if it's a non-index.php redirect that it goes into the .htaccess file. Seems like the regex in .htaccess is matching because the GET params are parsed properly.  If I request http://sub.domain.tld/amp/RID/whatever123 then RID is set to whatever123: array(1) {
  ["RID"]=>
  string(11) "whatever123"
} and /angel-page/ does exist I can navigate directly to it. I used top because I wanted priority in matching in the .htaccess file.

Comment: And what URL is showing when you get the 404? angel-page may exist, but is it getting resolved correctly by the htaccess? Or is it not even getting there and you are getting the 404 for sub.domain.tld/amp/RID/whatever123? As I said, its impossible for me to know whats happening without seeing it, so all I can do is point to potential problem areas in the hope that ones of them finally turns out to be the cause.

Comment: It looks like it's not matching what's in the .htaccess. ["query_vars"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["page"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["pagename"]=>
    string(22) "amp/RID/asldkfj0982340"
  }
  ["query_string"]=>
  string(35) "pagename=amp%2FRID%2Fasldkfj0982340"
  ["request"]=>
  string(22) "amp/RID/asldkfj0982340"
  ["matched_rule"]=>
  string(24) "(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$"
  ["matched_query"]=>
  string(41) "pagename=amp%2FRID%2Fasldkfj0982340&page="
  ["did_permalink"]=>
  bool(true)
}

Comment: Is this the rule that is actually getting triggered, or is it just a matching rule you found in the database? That looks like a rewrite rule from the WP database for the pagination rewrite rule - which is what I'd expect at some point because WP matches all requests to its own rewrite rules. However what I was asking was what URL shows in the browser location bar when you get the 404 error? That will help to determine whether its failing before or after the htaccess rule

Comment: The browser bar doesn't change.  But I thought it shouldn't with rewrites.

Comment: Hmmm, can't run apache_get_modules on this host I guess.

Comment: No, the location bar will show the rewritten URL, so if its not changing then the rule in htaccess doesn't appear to be getting triggered.

Comment: I tried to delete the check for <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> but WordPress just adds it back in.

Comment: I'll do a non WordPress .htaccess on the server and see if mod_rewrite.c is working.

Comment: It's working on that server and yes it does change the browser address bar.